# Strategies for old Local Storage data

Tags: local-storage

I have a site that stores data to Local Storage.
If I change my site, and a user has old, incompatible data in the Local Storage, an error will occur.

What are some good strategies of dealing with this issue?

Answer (score 0):

versioning?

on bootstrap you checking version, if user.version < current.version then clear all data from local storage